# Kaa User verifiers

Tags: kaa

Just wanted to confirm my understanding on the User Verifiers in Kaa.

The primary purpose of user verifier is to enable Kaa eventing and interaction between endpoints. Is there any other application of a user verifier ?

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the user verifiers in Kaa is to attach an endpoint to a particular Kaa user. That implies not only endpoint-to-endpoint communication within the scope of the same user, but also a number of other bindings and relations between features and data in Kaa.